# Arduino sketch unexpected behaviour

Tags: gsm, memory

I am currently in a arduino project to read some parameters from another microcontroller serially and the arduino is supposed to transmit these serially to dweet.io cloud. I use SIM900 modem for this. But my problem is that if i put some data to the variables, then the post to the cloud becomes unsuccessfull. Without any data in all parameters, the code runs fine.

Please find the code

```
char code[4] = {'\0'}, voltage[4] = {'\0'}, current[4] = {'\0'}, mcurrent[4] = {'\0'}, acurrent[4] = {'\0'}, power[4] = {'\0'}, pf[4] = {'\0'}, freq[4] = {'\0'}, temp[4] = {'\0'};
const char APN[18] = "bsnlnet";
byte dtype = 0;

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

void read_comp() {
    byte flag = 0, index = 0, l = 0;
    char c;
    char readings[8] = {'\0'};
    dtype = 0;

    do {
        while (Serial.available() && l == 0) {
            c = Serial.read();
            delay(20);

            if (c == '\n') {
                l = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                readings[index] = c;
                index++;
            }
        }

        readings[index] = '\0';
        index = 0;
        l = 0;

        if (readings[0] == 'v' || readings[0] == 'V') {             //check if received reading is voltage
            dtype = 1;
            flag = 1;

            if (readings[1] == 'o') {
                flag = 100;
            }
        } else if (readings[0] == 'c' || readings[0] == 'C') {  //check if received reading is current
            dtype = 2;
            flag = 1;

            if (readings[1] == 'u') {
                flag = 100;
            }
        } else if (flag == 1 && readings[1] == 'o') {
            dtype = 9;
            flag = 100;
        } else if (readings[0] == 'm' || readings[0] == 'M') {
            dtype = 3;
            flag = 1;

            if (readings[1] == 'c' && flag == 1) {
                flag = 100;
            }
        } else if (readings[0] == 'a' || readings[0] == 'A') {
            dtype = 4;
            flag = 1;

            if (readings[1] == 'c') {
                flag = 100;
            }
        } else if (readings[0] == 'p' || readings[0] == 'P') {
            flag = 1;

            if (readings[1] == 'o') {
                flag = 100;
                dtype = 5;
            } else if (readings[1] == 'f' || readings[1] == 'F') {
                flag = 100;
                dtype = 6;
            }
        } else if (readings[0] == 'f' || readings[0] == 'F') {
            dtype = 7;
            flag = 1;

            if (readings[1] == 'r') {
                flag = 100;
            }
        } else if (readings[0] == 't' || readings[0] == 'T') {
            dtype = 8;
            flag = 1;

            if (readings[1] == 'e') {
                flag = 100;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 100) {
            switch (dtype) {
                case 1:
                    voltage[0] = readings[3];
                    voltage[1] = readings[4];
                    voltage[2] = readings[5];
                    voltage[3] = readings[6];
                    voltage[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    current[0] = readings[3];
                    current[1] = readings[4];
                    current[2] = readings[5];
                    current[3] = readings[6];
                    current[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    mcurrent[0] = readings[3];
                    mcurrent[1] = readings[4];
                    mcurrent[2] = readings[5];
                    mcurrent[3] = readings[3];
                    mcurrent[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    acurrent[0] = readings[3];
                    acurrent[1] = readings[4];
                    acurrent[2] = readings[5];
                    acurrent[3] = readings[6];
                    acurrent[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    power[0] = readings[3];
                    power[1] = readings[4];
                    power[2] = readings[5];
                    power[3] = readings[6];
                    power[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    pf[0] = readings[3];
                    pf[1] = readings[4];
                    pf[2] = readings[5];
                    pf[3] = readings[6];
                    pf[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 7:
                    freq[0] = readings[3];
                    freq[1] = readings[4];
                    freq[2] = readings[5];
                    freq[3] = readings[6];
                    freq[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 8:
                    temp[0] = readings[3];
                    temp[1] = readings[4];
                    temp[2] = readings[5];
                    temp[3] = readings[6];
                    temp[4] = '\0';
                    flag = 0;
                    break;

                case 9:
                    code[0] = readings[3];
                    code[1] = readings[4];
                    code[2] = readings[5];
                    code[3] = readings[6];
                    code[4] = '\0';
                    dtype = 10;
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    } while (dtype != 10);
}

void modem_initialization(void) {
    char rec_data, r;
    byte network_status = 0 ;//network_status initialized as zero
    byte status_check = 0 ;//status_check initialized as zero
    byte Serial3_cnt = 0;//Serial3_cnt initialized as zero
    byte ok_flag = 0; //ok_flag initialized as zero
    byte count = 0; //count initialized as zero
    clear_rx_buffer();

    while (Serial3_cnt < 4) { // repeat entire loop until Serial3_cnt less than 5
        switch (Serial3_cnt) {
            case 0:
                clear_rx_buffer();//clearing receiving buffer
                Serial3.println(F("AT"));// Attention command to wake up Serial3 modem
                delay(1000);
                break;

            case 1:
                clear_rx_buffer();//clearing receiving buffer
                Serial3.println(F("ATE0"));//Command for disable echo
                delay(1000);
                break;

            /*case 2: clear_rx_buffer();//clearing receiving buffer
                   // Serial3.println("ATV0");// Command for numeric response after this '0'(zero) will be recieved instead of "OK"
                    delay(1000);
                    break;*/
            case 2:
                clear_rx_buffer();//clearing receiving buffer
                Serial3.println(F("AT&W"));// Command TO SAVE SETTINGS
                delay(1000);
                break;

            case 3:
                Serial3_cnt = 4;// exit from the loop
                break;

            default :
                break;
        }

        while (Serial3.available() > 0) {
            rec_data = Serial3.read();

            if (rec_data == 'O') { // 'o' is recieved
                ok_flag = 1;
            } else if (ok_flag == 1 && rec_data == 'K') { // 'K' is recieved
                Serial3_cnt ++;
                ok_flag = 0;
            } else if (rec_data == '0') { // '0'(zero) is recieved (numeric response)
                Serial3_cnt ++;
                ok_flag = 0;
            } else if (rec_data == '+') { // '+' is recieved message
                clear_rx_buffer();

                if (Serial3_cnt > 0) {
                    Serial3_cnt --;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Serial3_cnt = 0;
    ok_flag = 0;

    while (network_status == 0) { //wait for PIN READY
        if (status_check == 0) {
            delay(1000);
            status_check = 1 ;
            clear_rx_buffer();
            Serial3.println(F("AT+CPIN?")); //checkin PIN return ready(+CPIN: READY) with a valid simcard otherwise error
        }

        while (Serial3.available() > 0) {
            rec_data = Serial3.read();

            if (rec_data == '+' && status_check == 1) { // '+' is recieved
                status_check = 2 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'C' && status_check == 2) { // 'C' is recieved
                status_check = 3 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'P' && status_check == 3) { // 'P' is recieved
                status_check = 4 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'I' && status_check == 4) { // 'I' is recieved
                status_check = 5 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'N' && status_check == 5) { // 'N' is recieved
                status_check = 6 ;
            } else if (rec_data == ':' && status_check == 6) { // ':' is recieved
                status_check = 7 ;
            } else if (rec_data == ' ' && status_check == 7) { // ' ' is recieved
                status_check = 8 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'R' && status_check == 8) { // 'R' is recieved
                status_check = 9 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'E' && status_check == 9) { // 'E' is recieved
                status_check = 10 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'A' && status_check == 10) { // 'A' is recieved
                status_check = 11 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'D' && status_check == 11) { // 'D' is recieved
                status_check = 12 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'Y' && status_check == 12) { // 'Y' is recieved
                status_check = 13 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 0X0D && status_check == 13) { //Carriage return
                status_check = 14 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 0X0A && status_check == 14) { //Line Feed
                status_check = 15 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'O' && status_check == 15) { // '0' is recieved
                status_check = 16;
            } else if (rec_data == 'K' && status_check == 16) {
                clear_rx_buffer();
                status_check = 0 ;
                network_status = 1; //goto next step
            } else if (rec_data != 'R' && status_check == 8) { //+CPIN: NOT READY
                clear_rx_buffer();
                status_check = 0 ;
                network_status = 0; //repeat current step
            } else if (rec_data == 'M' && status_check == 3) { // in case of any message
                clear_rx_buffer();
                status_check = 0 ;
                network_status = 0; //repeat current step
            }
        }
    }

    while (network_status == 1) { //wait for SIM network registration
        if (status_check == 0) {
            delay(1000);
            status_check = 1 ;
            clear_rx_buffer();
            Serial3.println(F("AT+CREG?")); //checking for SIM card registration ,if registerd "+CREG: 0,1" will receive
        }

        while (Serial3.available() > 0) {
            rec_data = Serial3.read();

            if (rec_data == '+' && status_check == 1) { // '+' is recieved
                status_check = 2 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'C' && status_check == 2) { // 'C' is recieved
                status_check = 3 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'R' && status_check == 3) { // 'R' is recieved
                status_check = 4 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'E' && status_check == 4) { // 'E' is recieved
                status_check = 5 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'G' && status_check == 5) { // 'G' is recieved
                status_check = 6 ;
            } else if (rec_data == ':' && status_check == 6) { // ':' is recieved
                status_check = 7 ;
            } else if (rec_data == ' ' && status_check == 7) { // ' ' is recieved
                status_check = 8 ;
            } else if (rec_data == '0' && status_check == 8) { // '0' is recieved
                status_check = 9 ;
            } else if (rec_data == ',' && status_check == 9) { // ',' is recieved
                status_check = 10 ;
            } else if (rec_data == '1' && status_check == 10) { // '1' is recieved
                status_check = 11 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 0X0D && status_check == 11) { //Carriage return
                status_check = 12 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 0X0A && status_check == 12) { //Line Feed
                status_check = 12 ;
            } else if (rec_data == 'O' && status_check == 12) { // '0' is recieved
                status_check = 13;
            } else if (rec_data == 'K' && status_check == 13) {
                clear_rx_buffer();
                status_check = 0 ;
                network_status = 2; //goto next step
            } else if (rec_data != '1' && status_check == 10) { // +CREG: 0,2 not registered
                clear_rx_buffer();
                status_check = 0 ;
                network_status = 1; //repeat current step
            } else if (rec_data == 'M' && status_check == 3) { // in case of any message
                clear_rx_buffer();
                status_check = 0 ;
                network_status = 1; //repeat current step
            }
        }
    }

    Serial3_cnt = 0;

    while (Serial3_cnt < 4) { // repeat entire loop until Serial3_cnt less than 4
        switch (Serial3_cnt) {
            case 0:
                clear_rx_buffer();//clearing receiving buffer
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CMGF=1"));// Attention command to wake up Serial3 modem
                delay(1000);
                break;

            case 1:
                clear_rx_buffer();//clearing receiving buffer
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,0"));//Command to configure new message indication
                delay(1000);
                break;

            case 2:
                clear_rx_buffer();//clearing receiving buffer
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CMGD=1,4"));// Command to delete all received messages
                delay(1000);
                break;

            case 3:
                Serial3_cnt = 4;// exit from the loop
                break;

            default :
                break;
        }

        while (Serial3.available() > 0) {
            rec_data = Serial3.read();

            if (rec_data == 'O') { // '0'(zero) is recieved (numeric response)
                rec_data = Serial3.read();

                if (rec_data == 'K') {
                    Serial3_cnt ++;
                }
            } else if (rec_data == '+') { // '+' recieved ,before "AT+CIICR" command,may be any message
                clear_rx_buffer();

                if (Serial3_cnt > 0) {
                    Serial3_cnt --;
                }
            } else if (rec_data == 'E' && Serial3_cnt > 2) { // '4' recieved (error),in gprs initialisation commands
                clear_rx_buffer();
                Serial3_cnt = 4;
            }
        }
    }

    Serial3_cnt = 0;
}

void clear_rx_buffer(void) {
    Serial3.flush();
}


void gprs_init() {
    byte st = 1, i = 0, response = 0;
    char r[10];

    while (st <= 9) {
        delay(1000);
        clear_rx_buffer();

        switch (st) {
            case 1:
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CGATT?"));
                break;

            case 2:
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CIPSHUT"));
                break;

            case 3:
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CIPMUX=0"));
                break;

            case 4:
                response = cmd1_check(1);
                break;

            case 5:
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CIICR"));
                delay(1000);
                break;

            case 6:
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CIFSR"));
                break;

            case 7:
                response = cmd1_check(2);
                delay(2200);
                clear_rx_buffer();
                break;

            case 8:
                Serial3.println(F("AT+CIPSEND"));
                break;

            case 9:
                Serial3_send();
                ++st;
                break;
        }

        if (st == 10) {
            clear_rx_buffer();
        }

        delay(1000);

        while (Serial3.available() && st < 9 && st != 7 && st != 4) {
            r[i] = Serial3.read();
            i++;
        }

        i = 0;

        if (strstr(r, "ALREADY") != NULL) {
            Serial3.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
            delay(50);
            clear_rx_buffer();
            st = 2;
            r[0] = '\0';
        }

        if (strstr(r, "OK") != NULL || strstr(r, "+CGATT") != NULL || (strstr(r, ".") != NULL && st == 6) || strstr(r, ">") != NULL) {
            st++;
        } else if (strstr(r, "ERR") != NULL) {
            break;
        } else if (response == 1 && (st == 7 || st == 4)) {
            st++;
            response = 0;
        }
    }
}

char cmd1_check(short int o) {
    byte timout1 = 10500, m1, p1 = 0, resp1 = 0;
    char response1[25] = {'\0'};
    m1 = millis();
    clear_rx_buffer();

    if (o == 1) {
        Serial3.print(F("AT+CSTT="));
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print(APN);
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print(',');
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print(',');
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.println('"');
        delay(3000);
    } else if (o == 2) {
        Serial3.print(F("AT+CIPSTART="));
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print(F("TCP"));
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print(',');
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print(F("dweet.io"));
        Serial3.print('"');
        Serial3.print(',');
        Serial3.println(80);
        delay(2000);
    }

    do {
        p1 = 0;

        while (Serial3.available()) {
            response1[p1] = Serial3.read();
            p1++;
            delay(20);
        }

        if (strstr(response1, "OK") != NULL && o == 1) {
            resp1 = 1;
        } else if (strstr(response1, "ERR") != NULL) {
            resp1 = 2;
        } else if (strstr(response1, "CONNECT OK") != NULL && o == 2) {
            resp1 = 1;
        }
    } while ((millis() - m1) <= timout1 && resp1 == 0);

    return (resp1);
}

void Serial3_send() {
    Serial3.print("POST /dweet/for/");
    Serial3.print("mythingname");
    Serial3.print("?vo=");
    Serial3.print(voltage);
    Serial3.print("&cu=");
    Serial3.print(current);
    Serial3.print("&Mc=");
    Serial3.print(mcurrent);
    Serial3.print("&Ac=");
    Serial3.print(acurrent);
    Serial3.print("&Po=");
    Serial3.print(power);
    Serial3.print("&PF=");
    Serial3.print(pf);
    Serial3.print("&fr=");
    Serial3.print(freq);
    Serial3.print("&Te=");
    Serial3.print(temp);
    Serial3.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    Serial3.println("connection: keep-alive");
    Serial3.println();
    Serial3.println();
    Serial3.write(26);
    Serial3.println();
    delay(10000);
    Serial3.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
    delay(50);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial3.begin(9600);
    modem_initialization();
}

void loop() {
    dtype = 0;
    read_comp();
    gprs_init();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This **looks like** you are constructing the data to be sent as **GET** parameters (i.e as part of the querystring), whereas I believe dweet.io expects them as part of the **POST** body - [as seen here](https://dweet.io/play/#!/dweets/postDweet_post_0).

There seem to be many people [struggling to successfully send HTTP POSTs with a SIM900](http://google.com/?q=sim900%20post%20data), but I think [this answer outlines the correct sequence to make it work](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21688/send-json-via-post-on-sim900-shield-with-at-commands).